# Report of reputation to employer

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, reputation

I am a member of Stack Overflow.

Please let me know about:

1. Will it be legal If I want to show my reputation score to my employer?
2. If it is legal, is there a way which I can generate report from Stack Overflow about my reputation like a certificate?

If anyone know about that, please let me get suggestion.

Comment: The best way to prove it's your profile is to put some personal info in it - your real name, your E-Mail address, a URL....

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm Yup; and also, cross-link to your profile here from *other* profiles/sites that someone will know are also you. For example; my SO, Facebook, and blog profiles all link to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's *legal* to show anyone you want your profile, reputation, badges, etc.

As far as 'generating a report', I'm not being a smartass, but here's yours: https://stackoverflow.com/users/900284/frank That is, it's the link to your profile.

If you are looking for a way for Stack Overflow to *certify* that you are you, and your profile is *yours*; that's not going to happen. Stack Overflow does not have (and does not *want*) the necessary information about you to do that.

Comment: Thank for your answer @AndrewBarber , What I really want to do is print my reputation like a certificate document style. But by using this [link myProfile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/900284/frank) could only display me like a web page style. Please give me suggestion again.

Comment: @Frank Ummm... I'm sure that's not something Stack Exchange is going to do for you. I'm also fairly sure that there isn't any point whatsoever to doing it. If you wanted to create some *fake* certificate yourself... I would advise against it, but you're on your own if that's what you want.

Comment: thank for your suggestion @AndrewBarber.

Answer (score 3):

Your profile is publicly accessible: https://stackoverflow.com/users/900284/frank

You can share that with anyone you like. To check out what other people can see, log out and click the url.

[image]

You can also use the [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage), to generate the report "certificate" you want. But, what exactly would that be?